# Simple FFMPEG Concatenation

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to program an automation process to add a message at the beginning and end of an input video in Windows. I have a png being looped into a mp4 with a silent audio stream added on. This is the filter complex that I'm using:

```
    ffmpeg -i messageWithSilence.mp4 -i gif.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,format=yuv420p,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1,setsar=1[video_1]; 
    [0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo[audio_1]; 
    [1:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo[audio_2];
    [video_1][1:v][video_1]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[v_concat]; 
    [audio_1][audio_2][audio_1]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a_concat]" -map "[v_concat]" -map "[a_concat]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -r 30 -shortest "%output_name%.mp4"
```

Any ideas as to why I would be getting the error

> ```
> Stream specifier 'video_1' in filtergraph description matches no streams
> ```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part of your filtergraph

```
[video_1][1:v][video_1]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[v_concat];
```

you used the link label `[video_1]` twice. The first occurrence of it “consumes” the previously defined output pad `[video_1]` output, so the second one has no chance to connect to it.

---

*Solution:*

You may append the `split` filter to your first filterchain (i.e. just before the `[video_1]` output pad label)

```
...,setsar=1,split[video_1][video_2];
```

to create 2 identical video outputs, and then replace the second occurrence of `[video_1]` with `[video_2]` in your `concat` filter:

```
[video_1][1:v][video_2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[v_concat];
```

---

*Note:*

You have to perform a similar procedure for your `[audio_1]` label – you used it twice as input label, too.